# pandas "Cannot concat indices that do not have same number of levels" error returned when trying to apply an extractall function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make an email extraction script that reads Outlook emails and extract the information into a pandas dataframe.

I've run into errors when trying to extract dates from the message body:

```
#group messages by Subject so that individual emails are grouped in threads 
dfgroup = df.groupby('Subject') 

#attempt to extract all the dates mentioned in the email body
temp = dfgroup['Message'].apply(lambda x: x.str.extractall(r'(?P<extract>(?P<month>(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December))\s(?P<date>\d{2})\,\s(?P<year>\d{4})\s(?P<time>\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s(PM|AM)))'))
```

However, I received the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\tioxr\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 573, in _make_concat_multiindex
raise AssertionError("Cannot concat indices that do"

AssertionError: Cannot concat indices that do not have the same number of levels
```

Any ideas on how to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' `groupby` builds a list of DataFrames, applies a function over each of them and ultimately concatenates to a single output DataFrame.
In your case, the last step fails as one of the groups returns an empty DataFrame.

Try this:

```
list_df = []
for key, group in df.groupby('Subject'):
    list_df.append(
        group.Message.apply(some_func)
    )

out_df = pd.concat(list_df)
```